# Need an Applescript to handle specific incoming mail.

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, applescript, contacts

Here's what I'd like the Applescript to do: upon receiving an email (I'm using Apple Mail) from a specific address, I'd like, firstly, that email to be deleted (not just moved to trash), and secondly, to send an email to myself with the simple message: "You got mail." Upon receiving that message, I would then go and read the deleted message using my account's web access (retrieved messages there are only deleted a month later).

The issue I'm trying to solve is that I don't want the emails from that contact to be easily accessible by anyone using my computer. I could create a new email address just to receive mail from that contact, and keep that address completely off of Apple Mail, but that would force me to manually check the account from the web every couple of hours.

Hopefully that's clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an Applescript. In Mail.app go to Preferences > Rules and add a rule that will delete any email that meets your specifications.

Comment: Yes, that part is easy. The trouble is letting me know that an email has been deleted that way. Haven't found a way to do that in Mail.

Comment: I found someone who needed to execute an Applescript from a Mail.app rule. Not knowing beans about Applescript I am not sure if this is helpful: http://www.macandiostips.com/Mac_and_iOS_Tips/Mac_Tips_%26_Tricks/Entries/2013/8/2_How_to_make_AppleScripts_Execute_Correctly_under_Mail_Rules.html